# What's right for me: htAccess, form submittion, HTTP header authentication w/ PHP?

Tags: php, http, authentication, .htaccess

I am creating a website with multiple sections--admin, client, user, and anonymous--each user group having less access then the next. I am wondering what form of authentication would be best for my use?

I have heard the if you are just dealing with a websites then a web form is for you (because it's prettier). HTTP header authentication with PHP is said to get clunky/sloppy. htAcess is pretty much the hard core of various authentication methods I have looked up, but is it too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for the form (a **session** really).
Nowadays it's the only option.

Comment: Using a session was originally my intention, but I say the other possibilities and wondered.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing things.

Your three options are basically two:

- Use HTTP authentication
- Do not use HTTP authentication

Whether it's handled by an .htaccess file or not is another matter. You can do HTTP authentication with Apache and PHP, and you can do non-HTTP authentication with Apache and PHP (though usually you do non-HTTP auth with PHP and HTTP auth with Apache).

Apache can defer the authentication to several backend and frontend modules (e.g. you can use CAS). Apache provides out-of-the-box (no dated sourceforge module...) for the following database backends: FreeTDS, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite 2/3 and an ODBC connector.

Personally, I dislike HTTP authentication. Usually a form will is more user friendly and you can provide links such as "Forgot your password?" and "Username not found".

I'd also go with implementing the authentication in PHP, because it's more portable (you can swap the web server).

Comment: well there is a difference. what to protect (a whole directory or php scripts only) and how to maintain users database (mysql or .htpasswd). Not a minor one

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel You can use a MySQL backend with Apache authentication (or any other backend for that matter). No need for .htpasswd.

Comment: by installing some ancient handmade modules from sourceforge? no, thanks

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I'm almost certain a mysql backend authentication modules comes with the Apache distribution.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel You're right, it's not included due to licensing issues. I've used PostgreSQL in the past, though. Still, writing an Apache backend module for authentication is not that complicated...

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Ok, maybe it's included after all: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/apr/apr/trunk/dbd/

Answer (score 0):

First off, for your application you should go for the simpler login form / session method. Because you want in-application user groups, it's only senseful to also use in-application authentication. Technically for the permission system it makes no difference which auth method is used. But you know, for simplicity and keeping all authorization stuff together...

The hatred against HTTP authentication is misgued, btw. It's the stronger authentication method, if you use HTTP Digest; which OTH is difficult to implement in PHP.
It's a usability nightmare only if you do it wrong. Practically a HTTP logon can be initiated with a login form as well. Using XMLHttpRequest can successfully trigger HTTP Authentication. And with a little more work (401 and new realm), pretty logouts are possible too. If no Javascript is enabled it falls back on the boring login dialog / readline obviously. But I've personally used a text-only browser for a while, and I tended to like that more.

Also, if your admin group is serious business (raw database access tools etc.), you should apply both methods. Make the admin interface separate from the application, apply login form and .htaccess restrictions. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Do NOT make the mistake of confusion Authorization with Authentication.  Authorization is purely your application space.  Authorization is something you can delegate to Apache.  It would be nice if Apache had an option called AuthenticateRedirectPage, where you could specify a form template it would use to authenticate the user.  Don't know how possible this is...  HTTP Auth is a browser/server interaction...

Comment: @Chris Kaminski It's certainly possible. The CAS authentication module forwards you to the CAS authentication page and keeps state itself. I'm not sure if someone's written a module as you described though.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I never thought of the possibility of using more then one method at once. Since, the admin group would be "serious business" it sounds like a good route to try.